# Can a dotnet core library app use the appsettings.json file from the consuming application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, net-library

Hi I am trying to set up a dotnet core library app that requires certain information from a appsettings.json to run.  I understand how to have an application use the appsettings.json file via the builder etc.  However I also want my library to use this file for its own configuration.  Obviously the consuming app would have to know the settings to have in the appsettings.json file but for my purposes that is not a problem.  Does anyone have an example of this working?  What I have found so far are not that great and involve loading the appsettings.json every time we instantiate the configuration class in the library.  There must be a better way than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly **Options** are created for!

You should not read settings file - DI will give you strongly-typed class/struct with parameters you need. Loaded from all configured sources (appsettings.json, environment variables etc), and updated automatically (if required/configured).

Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) - sample is pretty short and copy-pasting it here isn't wise.